# Private Conference call

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am building a simple app with Twilio to create a private conference call. This means that only specific numbers who call in will be added to the conference, all other numbers will be denied. I am using ngrok to get my locally hosted project online. The problem is that right now, anyone phone number who calls into the conference can join, regardless of the "if" statement. I only want the "moderator" and "attendee" to be able to call in. Here is what I have so far:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

const accountSid = 'blah blah blah';
const authToken = 'blah blah blah';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;
const urlencoded = require('body-parser').urlencoded;

const moderator = "+11234567890";
const attendee = '+10987654321';

app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/voice', (request, response) => {
    const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
    const dial = twiml.dial();

    if(request.body.From == attendee || request.body.From == moderator){
        dial.conference('Room1234', {
            startConferenceOnEnter: true,
            endConferenceOnExit: true
        });
    } else {
        twiml.reject()
        dial.conference('Room1234', {
            startConferenceOnEnter: false
        });
    }
    response.type('text/xml');
    response.send(twiml.toString());
});

console.log('Twilio Client app HTTP server running at 
http://127.0.0.1:8080');
app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Please mention the issue you need help with

Comment: The problem is that right now, anyone phone number who calls into the conference can join, regardless of the "if" statement. I only want the "moderator" and "attendee" to be able to call in. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `dial()` after `reject()`, try something like this:

```
app.post('/voice', (request, response) => {
    const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

    if (request.body.From === attendee || request.body.From === moderator) {
        const dial = twiml.dial();
        dial.conference('Room1234', {
            startConferenceOnEnter: true,
            endConferenceOnExit: true
        });

    } else {
        twiml.reject();

    }

    response.type('text/xml');
    response.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it.